# Android - Data Binding for Animation view

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

i have some problem to use data binding for animation view without using @BindingAdapter annotation. I want to use with Observable class so i can start the animation every time. I have try this code but nothing effect for the view.

```
public ObservableField<Animation> animation = 
           new ObservableField<>(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.box_bounce));
```

and the xml attribute :

```
android:layoutAnimation="@{viewModel.animation}"
```

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i found solution for this problem.
i cannot use Observable class for animation but i can use Observable class for boolean. I just set true or false to start and stop animation but i must use the @BindingAdapter annotation.

XML attribute :

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.MainViewModel" />
</data>

<ImageView
...
animation="@{viewModel.isAnimation}"
... />
```

View Model Class :

```
public ObservableBoolean isAnimation=new ObservableBoolean(false);

@BindingAdapter("animation")
public static void setAnimation(ImageButton view, boolean isAnimation) {
    if (isAnimation) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.box_bounce);
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
        view.startAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

and i just start and stop animation like this `isAnimation.set(true);` and `isAnimation.set(true);`

Comment: You could pass just the R.anim.xxx identifier to the animation custom binder and expect int as parameter.